# Associations strange behavior

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, model-associations, ef-model-first

I found a following issue regarding EF5 running under .NET 4.0, in Model First approach:

I have following auto-generated entity:

```vb
Partial Public Class Notice

    Private _id As Integer
    Public Property id As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Friend Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property order_id As Integer
    Public Property employee_id As Integer
    Public Property sysdate As Datetime
    Public Property content As String

    Public Overridable Property order As Order
    Public Overridable Property employee As Employee

End Class
```

Notice entity is associated with Order entity and Employee entity by 1 (Order, Employee) to many (Notice) relationship.

Afterward, Order entity has also association with Employee entity: many (Order) to 1 (Employee) relationship.

Then, I expect the following unit test to fail, because of Notice entity relation to Employee entity violation (I don't assign notice1.employee navigation property):

```vb
<TestMethod()>
    <ExpectedException(GetType(DbUpdateException))>
    Public Sub ShouldNotAllowSaveNoticeWithoutAssignedEmployee()

        Dim notice1 = CreateNewNotice() ' returned entity has not set any relation
        notice1.order= CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities()

        DbContext.noticeSet.Add(notice1)
        DbContext.SaveChanges()

    End Sub
```

But in result test is passed. In Database, Notice->employee_id value is equal to Order->employee_id value, what is not expected, because these foreign keys may point to different Employee object. I expected that i have to set up notice1.employee navigation property myself, and I would like to get `DbUpdateException` exception if i forget to do it.

What is the reason of this strange EF5 behavior?

*Update:*

`CreateNewNotice()` and `CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities()` implementation:

```vb
 Protected Function CreateNewNotice(Optional ByVal suffix As Int32 = 1) As Notice

        Dim notice1 = New Notice() With {
            .sysdate = DateTime.Now,
            .content = Description & suffix ' Description is constant, for testing purposes
        }

        Return notice1 

    End Function

Protected Function CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities(Optional ByVal suffix As Int32 = 1) As Order

        Dim order1 = CreateNewOrder(suffix) ' returned entity has not set any relation
        order1.employee = CreateNewEmployee(suffix)
        order1.customer = CreateNewCustomerWithAllRequiredRelatedEntities(suffix)
        order1.seller = CreateNewSeller(suffix)

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            order1.notices.Add(CreateNewNotice(i)) ' created notices have not initialized relations
        Next

        Return order1

    End Function
```

Comment: post the implementation of `CreateNewNotice()` and `CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities()`

Comment: I have posted these implementations. What is also strange for me, in `CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities()` method there are created three Notice entities without relations set, but these notices are saved in database, and have foreign keys set.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without access to all the code.  One suggestion is to create a DB context object per test and pass it around to your helper functions when needed (i.e. code procedurally and not in an object oriented fashion, which is fine for unit test methods)

Comment: In test class there is DbContext protected property, and it is re-instantiated for each test in `<TestInitialize()>` attributed  method, then disposed in `<TestCleanup()>` attributed method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recognized this issue, and it looks like there is a different behavior of EF5 depending on whether we use 'foreign key associations' or 'independent associations' (some informations about relationships in EF: [Relationships and Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564))

Lets assume that we use EF5 Model First Approach (with .NET 4.5). Lets take in consideration automatically generated entity classes, related to example showed up in topic's questions:

```vb
Partial Public Class Employee
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property firstname As String
    Public Property lastname As String

    Public Overridable Property Notices As ICollection(Of Notice) = New HashSet(Of Notice)
    Public Overridable Property Orders As ICollection(Of Order) = New HashSet(Of Order)

End Class

Partial Public Class Order
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property Employee_id As Integer
    Public Property article As String

    Public Overridable Property Notices As ICollection(Of Notice) = New HashSet(Of Notice)
    Public Overridable Property Employee As Employee

End Class

Partial Public Class Notice
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property Employee_id As Integer
    Public Property Order_id As Integer
    Public Property sysdate As Date
    Public Property content As String

    Public Overridable Property Employee As Employee
    Public Overridable Property Order As Order

End Class
```

This entities classes use 'foreign key associations' and 'independent associations'.
Then, we have the following unit tests class:

```vb
<TestClass()>
Public Class UnitTests

    Protected DbContext As DbModelContext

    <TestInitialize()>
    Public Sub TestInitialize()

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-us")
        DbContext = New DbModelContext()

    End Sub

    <TestCleanup()>
    Public Sub TestCleanup()

        DbContext.Dispose()

    End Sub

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub Test1()

        Dim notice1 = CreateNewNotice()
        notice1.Order = CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities()

        DbContext.NoticeSet.Add(notice1)
        DbContext.SaveChanges() ' no DbUpdateException exception

        Assert.AreEqual(notice1.Employee.id, notice1.Order.Employee.id)
        Assert.AreEqual(notice1.Employee.id, notice1.Order.Notices.First().Employee.id)

    End Sub

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub Test2()

        Dim notice1 = CreateNewNotice()
        notice1.Order = CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities()

        DbContext.NoticeSet.Add(notice1)

        Dim employee2 = CreateNewEmployee()

        DbContext.EmployeeSet.Add(employee2)

        DbContext.SaveChanges() 'DbUpdateException exception

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create new Order object along with required associated objects,
    ''' however related Notice objects do not have assigned required associated objects
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Function CreateNewOrderWithAllRequiredAndRelatedEntities(Optional ByVal suffix As Int32 = 1) As Order

        Dim order1 = CreateNewOrder(suffix)
        order1.Employee = CreateNewEmployee(suffix)

        For i = suffix To suffix + 2

            order1.Notices.Add(CreateNewNotice(i))

        Next

        Return order1

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create new Order object without required associated objects
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Function CreateNewOrder(Optional ByVal suffix As Int32 = 1) As Order

        Dim order1 = New Order() With {
                .article = "article" & suffix
            }

        Return order1

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create new Employee object required without associated objects
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Function CreateNewEmployee(Optional ByVal suffix As Int32 = 1) As Employee

        Dim employee1 = New Employee() With {
                .firstname = "firstname" & suffix,
                .lastname = "lastname" & suffix
            }

        Return employee1

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create new Notice object without associated objects
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Function CreateNewNotice(Optional ByVal suffix As Int32 = 1) As Notice

        Dim notice1 = New Notice() With {
            .sysdate = DateTime.Now,
            .content = "Description" & suffix
        }

        Return notice1

    End Function

End Class
```

If we run tests, `Test1()` passes, but `Test2()` fails with exception:

**System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException**: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Model1.NoticeEmployee' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Model1.NoticeEmployee' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

Conclusions:

Inside `Test1()` there is only one `Employee` object and one `Order` object in the `DbContext`. Relations which are not set in code (`Notice.Employee`, `Notice.Order`) are automatically set up by EF within `DbContext.SaveChanges()` statement. Inside `Test2()` there are two `Employee` object in `DbContext`, so `Notice.Employee` has not automatically assigned value.

What is strange, if we remove foreign key properties from model entities, in order to have only 'independent associations' functionality, both tests fails with the same **System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException** exception.

Similarly, if we remove navigation properties from model entities, in order to have only 'foreign key associations' functionality, both tests fails with the same exception.

Comment: +1 Well done! I've been staring at this a few times but didn't have a clue. I was afraid it was a bug.